# ufw disable does not disable ufw on system startup

Tags: ufw

my mysql port 3306 was not accessible on one of my virtual machines runing Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. To fix it i entered

```
sudo ufw diable
```

and got the answer:

```
Firewall stopped and disabled on system startup
```

then the port 3306 is accessible via telnet from a remote system.
After a while (reboot?) the access is again not possible.

**What might be going on here and how can i debug/fix this?**

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/174646/how-do-i-find-my-firewall-is-blocking-mysql

says

```
sudo ufw allow out 3306/tcp  
sudo ufw allow in 3306/tcp
```

should work as a workaround.
The strange thing is - only if I do

```
sudo ufw disable
```

will the port be accessible for while.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo ufw allow mysql`
is the work around i used since i only got a downvote for my question so far

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41319291/ufw-blocks-most-ports-until-disabled-and-re-enabled-after-reboot

seems to have a similar quirk with ufw